# What query to wikimedia api allow to get article categories?

Tags: mediawiki-api

Many articles of Wikipedia contains categories, for example article `Mathematics` labeled as

[image]

I try next API query:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=mathematics&prop=categories
```

but it returns other categories...

1. What query to wikimedia api allow to get article categories (topics)?
2. How I can get information about this categories hierarchy?

Comment: You could also add `&cllimit=500&clprop=hidden`. That will list both hidden and not hidden categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing [hidden categories](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories#Hidden_categories). You can tell the API to not fetch hidden categories using the `&clshow=!hidden` option:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=mathematics&prop=categories&clshow=!hidden